# RxJS distinctUntilChanged - object comparison

Tags: angular, reactive-programming, rxjs

I have a stream of objects and I need to compare if the current object is not the same as the previous and in this case emit a new value. I found distinctUntilChanged operator should do exactly what I want, but for some reason, it never emits value except the first one. If I remove distinctUntilChanged values are emitted normally.

My code:

```ts
export class SettingsPage {
    static get parameters() {
        return [[NavController], [UserProvider]];
    }

    constructor(nav, user) {
        this.nav = nav;
        this._user = user;

        this.typeChangeStream = new Subject();
        this.notifications = {};
    }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.typeChangeStream
            .map(x => {console.log('value on way to distinct', x); return x;})
            .distinctUntilChanged(x => JSON.stringify(x))
            .subscribe(settings => {
                console.log('typeChangeStream', settings);
                this._user.setNotificationSettings(settings);
            });
    }

    toggleType() {
        this.typeChangeStream.next({
            "sound": true,
            "vibrate": false,
            "badge": false,
            "types": {
                "newDeals": true,
                "nearDeals": true,
                "tematicDeals": false,
                "infoWarnings": false,
                "expireDeals": true
            }
        });
    }

    emitDifferent() {
        this.typeChangeStream.next({
            "sound": false,
            "vibrate": false,
            "badge": false,
            "types": {
                "newDeals": false,
                "nearDeals": false,
                "tematicDeals": false,
                "infoWarnings": false,
                "expireDeals": false
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `typeChangeStream` an Observable? Hard to tell what's wrong without seeing what code is creating that / etc.

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for guidelines to deal with 'it does not work' questions. Basically post a minimally verifiable example that reproduces the error, and post the expected behaviour and how it is different from the current behavior. Talk about JSON stringifying you need to know that it is not a bullet proof method for checking equality of objects. {"a" : 2, "b":1} is for example different from {"b":1, "a":2} while these are the same objects

Comment: Sorry for that, i added more code. I don't need bullet proof object equality check, i am sure in this case object will be everytime i same order.

Comment: did u solve this problem? i have the same with BehaviorSubject, and it emits prev and curr same result, wtf..

Comment: @DanielSuchý it would be good IMO to accept the answer that did work for you

Answer (score 67):

I had the same problem, and fixed it with using JSON.stringify to compare the objects:

`.distinctUntilChanged((a, b) => JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b))`

This code will work if the attriutes are in the same order, if not it may break, so here's a quick fix for that (be careful this method is slower)

`.distinctUntilChanged((a, b) => JSON.stringify(a).split('').sort().join('') === JSON.stringify(b).split('').sort().join(''))`

Comment: I am filling in my input my unit cost for a product, with the same logic, but now I can only type 1 number at a time , unless i go back and click on the field. I would like to be able to type in multiple digits at a time which is the normal default. How can I do this

Comment: Have you tried the throttling or debouncing rxJS operators ?

Comment: that was the 1st thing I thought of, to use debounce but what I realised was when I type in the 1st digit the input loses focus then after the time span the values are emitted so it doesnt allow me to finish typing

Comment: thanks this save my butt, angular's valuesChanged keeps emitting values even though nothing was changed.  This object comparison put an end to that for me.

Comment: this will give you incorrect `true` when you `delete` a property and add it back.

Comment: I didn't understand your scenario, JSON.stringify will simply convert the object to string. Even if you don't have the same properties order it won't work !

Comment: This is why I said that this is a dirty but working code. Because it has a lot of limits but it's fast AF.

Comment: `JSON.stringify({a:1, b:2}) === JSON.stringify({b:2, a:1})` this is false, while the result should have been ture

Comment: @Reza yes that’s why I said dirty, because it will check properties order. But it solves majority of cases, where you have exact same objects, you can consider this solution like ===

Comment: Just gonna repeat #Reza. Not a fan of "opinion" that this is ok because it is "dirty" - JSON.stringify({a:1, b:2}) === JSON.stringify({b:2, a:1}) this is false, while the result should have been true - Reza

Comment: @TamusJRoyce using the second option that sorts the string solves this order issue with more costs (it's slower) but in major cases you dont need to sort the object.

Comment: @MehdiBenmoha still messes up objects like dates and such. Better to stick with a robust method then serialization. Ben's solution is deep-object-diff. With structuredClone, I am surprised to not see a likewise proper standard deep compare.

Answer (score 36):

When you have lodash in your application anyway, you can simply utilize lodash's `isEqual()` function, which does a deep comparison and perfectly matches the signature of `distinctUntilChanged()`:

```
.distinctUntilChanged(isEqual),
```

Or if you have `_` available (which is not recommended anymore these days):

```
.distinctUntilChanged(_.isEqual),
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean in the sentence: "Or if you have _ available (which is not recommended anymore these days):" because you literally just said if you have lodash in your application you can utilize lodash's isEqual() function, but isn't using "_" the way to use lodash to call the isEqual method??

Comment: @Bobby_Cheh When you import the `_`-Symbol, this includes *all* of lodash's functionality, whether you use it or not. This cannot be reduced to the really needed ones later to reduce the resulting bundle size in a build process (this is called "Tree Shaking", because all unconnected things fall of :-) ). When you just  require the single functions you need, it's only theses that get bound to your final program bundle: e.g. `import {isEqual} from 'lodash'`. Now it's tree-shakeable, so all the functions of lodash you didn't use (probably most part of lodash ;-) ) will not be included.

Answer (score 25):

I finally figure out where problem is. Problem was in version of RxJS, in V4 and earlier is different parameters order than V5.

RxJS 4:

> distinctUntilChanged = function (keyFn, comparer)

RxJS 5:

> distinctUntilChanged = function (comparer, keyFn)

**In every docs today, you can find V4 parameters order, beware of that!**

Comment: How did you fix this? What did you change? If you can tell this it would be great.

Comment: @Harsimer swap comparer and key function

Answer (score 15):

You can also *wrap* the original `distinctUntilChanged` function.

```js
function distinctUntilChangedObj<T>() {
  return distinctUntilChanged<T>((a, b) => JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b));
}
```

This lets you use it just like the original.

```js
$myObservable.pipe(
  distinctUntilChangedObj()
)
```

### Cavets

This method also has several pitfalls as some commenters have pointed out.

1. This will fail if the objects fields are ordered differently;

```js
JSON.stringify({a:1, b:2}) === JSON.stringify({b:2, a:1})
// will return false :(
```

2. This `JSON.stringify` will also throw an error if the object has circular references. For example stringify'ing something from the `firebase sdk` will lead you to these errors:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

### Robust Solution

Use the [deep-object-diff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-object-diff) library instead of `JSON.stringify`. This will solve the above problems

```js
import { detailedDiff } from 'deep-object-diff';

function isSame(a, b) {
  const result = detailedDiff(a, b); 
  const areSame = Object.values(result)
    .every((obj) => Object.keys(obj).length === 0);
  return areSame;
}

function distinctUntilChangedObj<T>() {
  return distinctUntilChanged<T>((a, b) => isSame(a, b));
}
```

Comment: even though it works, it messes with the pipeline objects

Comment: @Frik how so? `JSON.stringify()` shouldn't mess/mutate anything right? If you have _circular json_ in your objects, then you might need to use another package which can stringify it properly https://www.npmjs.com/package/circular-json

Comment: you are correct.  However, there seems to be a bug with WebStorm where it does not see the value o in the tap operator... so you don't have code completion for some reason...

from([
      { name: 'Brian' },
    ]).pipe(
      distinctUntilChangedObj(),
      tap(o => console.log(o.name))
    ).subscribe();

Comment: If you're using typescript, then you could also do `function distinctUntilChangedObj<T>() { return distinctUntilChanged<T>((a, b) => JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b)); }`. This will preserve the type correctly, but only if you're using _typescript_

Comment: Nice answer! This will be very useful.

Comment: Just gonna repeat #Reza. Not a fan of "opinion" that this is ok because it is "dirty" - JSON.stringify({a:1, b:2}) === JSON.stringify({b:2, a:1}) this is false, while the result should have been true - Reza

Comment: That's true @TamusJRoyce, there's other ways it can fail too, for example circular references in the objects. I've updated answer to address these problems

Answer (score 11):

From RxJS v6+
there is distinctUntilKeyChanged

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/distinctuntilkeychanged.html

```
const source$ = from([
  { name: 'Brian' },
  { name: 'Joe' },
  { name: 'Joe' },
  { name: 'Sue' }
]);

source$
  // custom compare based on name property
  .pipe(distinctUntilKeyChanged('name'))
  // output: { name: 'Brian }, { name: 'Joe' }, { name: 'Sue' }
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: FYI, if `name` was an object like `{name: {first: 'Brian'}}` this doesn't work as it doesn't compare the the entire objects.

Answer (score 5):

Mehdi's solution although fast but wouldn't work if the order is not maintained. Using one of [deep-equal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-equal) or [fast-deep-equal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-deep-equal) libraries:

```
.distinctUntilChanged((a, b) => deepEqual(a, b))
```

Comment: there is structuredClone polyfil/new standard. Why isn't there structuredEquals replacement for lodash? lodash isn't compiler friendly when it comes to tree shaking

Answer (score 3):

The answers suggesting a deep compare all fail if the observable is actually emitting a modified version of *the same object*, as the "last" value that is passed to the comparison will be the same as the current, every time.

We've hit this using a BehaviorSubject where it just so happens that the same object is passed to .next() each time.

In this case, there is no solution using the default distinctUntilChanged, no matter what comparison function you use.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the value mutably, none of the other answers work. If you need to work with mutable data structures, you can use **[`distinctUntilChangedImmutable`](https://toms.blog/distinct-until-changed-immutable/)**, which deep copies the previous value and if no comparison function is passed in, will assert that the previous and the current values deep equals each other (not === assertion).

Comment: Class constructor Subscriber cannot be invoked without 'new' at new DistinctUntilChangedSubscriber

Answer (score 0):

You can also make your own filter:

```
function compareObjects(a: any, b: any): boolean {
  return JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b);
}

export function distinctUntilChangedObject() {
  return function<T>(source: Observable<T>): Observable<T> {
    return new Observable(subscriber => {
      let prev: any;
      let first = true;
      source.subscribe({
        next(value) {
          if (first) {
            prev = value;
            subscriber.next(value);
            first = false;
          } else if (!compareObjects(prev, value)) {
            prev = value;
            subscriber.next(value);
          }
        },
        error(error) {
          subscriber.error(error);
        },
        complete() {
          subscriber.complete();
        }
      });
    });
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those considering JsonStringify to be slow or unreliable (because of different property order) the example below might help for an object array. Its primary key is a property called 'id'.

```
same(prev: BasketItem[], next: BasketItem[]): boolean {
    if (prev?.length != next?.length)
        return false;

    // verify that all of the ids are contained in both arrays
    for (var i = 0; i < prev.length; i++) {
        if (!prev.some(x => x.id == next[i].id))
            return false;
        if (!next.some(x => x.id == prev[i].id))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I call it a as follows

```
.pipe(distinctUntilChanged((prev, curr) => this.same(prev, curr)))
```

example for the object array :

> [  {id:'d7273481-e99b-4d72-84eb-826fbf52e4e9' , price:'44.02'}
>
> ,
> {id:'11f125e3-c190-4177-a656-7b107a7d687c' , price:'54.88'} ]

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this:

```
import { cloneDeep, isEqual } from 'lodash-es'

observable$.pipe(
  ... other stuff
  map(x => cloneDeep(x)),
  distinctUntilChanged(isEqual)
  ... other stuff
)
```

if `x` is getting mutated, `cloneDeep` seems to be necessary to make `distinctUntilChanged` work