# distinctUntilChanged not working for same value as previous

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, rxjs, formgroups

Something strange happening here. I have a form with 3 fields: a `string` and two `objects`.
The both objects get values from `mat-select`. Here, if I select again the current value, will not be emitted any event. For the string, is another situation (named `country`)

The country field is a value get from one of three buttons as:

ts:

```
countries = ['en', 'de', 'es'];


countryChanged(country: string): void {
   this.form.patchValue({
     country
   });
}
```

html:

```
<button *ngFor="let country of countries" (click)="countryChanged(country)">
   {{country}}
</button>
```

now, the problem is that, even if I press the same button, it will trigger again the form `valueChanges`, even the value is the same as the previous.

```
this.form.valueChanges.pipe(
  distinctUntilChanged() // ?????
).subscribe(data => {
  // do stuff
});
```

Why `distinctUntilChanged()` don't do its work here?

I know I can avoid it simple, with an if condition inside `countryChanged()` method, but I want to understand why `distinctUntilChanged()` don't do its job.

```
countryChanged(country: string): void {
    if (country === this.form.get('country').value) {
       return;
    }

    this.form.patchValue({
       country
    });
}
```

Comment: Because it's an object, what is compared in the `distinctUntilChanged()`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37172395/rxjs-distinctuntilchanged-object-comparison

Comment: damn, almost good, but if I don't use `startsWith` inside `valueChanges.pipe()`, `distinctUntilChanges` will not trigger for first time and will pass to `subscribe` function. And I really can not use `startsWith` here :))

Comment: Why can't you use `startsWith`? If I'm correct using `startsWith(null)` shouldn't be a problem. This null is not really set as a value and following `distinctUntilChanged` will handle it correctly.

Comment: Sorry for later answer. I have some complex logique in form `valueChanges`, which can update route `params`, will update the url and emit an event to params subscriber (which is the first action of the component). Also have some other functions which will throw errors for undefined objects if I'll start with `null` values. Based on form inputs, I'll do some http requests (or sockets requests) or update router params and restart all the  flow

Answer (score 4):

Objects are reference types and "===" used by distinctUntilChanged will not work.  You can compare the values of the previous and current emitted ones using **JSON.stringify**,  you will be able to compare the value of your two objects

```
.pipe(
  distinctUntilChanged((previous, current) => JSON.stringify(previous) === JSON.stringify(current))
)
```

Here is the code that will show you the difference between using **JSON.stringify** or without it

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-hjq436?file=index.ts